# Export DataTable to Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable, export

I have a DataTable with 30+ columns and 6500+ rows.I need to dump the whole DataTable values into an Excel file.Can anyone please help with the C# code.I need each column value to be in a cell.To be precise,I need the exact looking copy of DataTable in an Excel File.Please help.

Thanks,
Vix

Comment: You could try the technique described here: [C-Sharp Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/exportxl_asp2_dc11032006003657AM/exportxl_asp2_dc.aspx)

Comment: Almost all answer here write a (HtmlTextWriter) string or have Interop code. DO NOT USE EITHER. This will cause you problems later on with DateTime and Decimal formatting. Also Excel will give a warning because you are not generating a "real" Excel file but a HTML page with an .xls extension. Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513057/5836671).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

use this code...

```
    dt = city.GetAllCity();//your datatable
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Of all the convoluted articles I came across on the web to accomplish this it was nice to find a short, simple solution that just works. Many thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions to force Excel to treat all fields as string regardless of the data? For example, do not drop the leading zeros in  '0000012'. I tried prefixing the values with an apostrophe but the apostrophe showed up in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Why is it that this doesn't actually do anything for me?  Even if I copy it verbatim, it just doesn't download the file...

Comment: What is used to merge the cells?                                                                 \t is used to move to the new cell in same row, \n for move to the new row,

Comment: This code downloads a CSV file, without any formatting; if you need more flexibility with merging cells, background cell color and so on, you should read the other answers to this question.

Comment: There are many solutions to accomplish this, with or without dependencies, but it's the shortest,easiest and probably fastest one. Thanks for sharing with us.

Comment: It's not a pure Excel file, it's only text saved as Excel :(

Answer (score 11):

This snippet could be faster to implement:

```
// Example data
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.AddRange(new[]{ new DataColumn("Key"), new DataColumn("Value") });
foreach (string name in Request.ServerVariables)
    table.Rows.Add(name, Request.ServerVariables[name]);

// This actually makes your HTML output to be downloaded as .xls file
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFile.xls");

// Create a dynamic control, populate and render it
GridView excel = new GridView();
excel.DataSource = table;
excel.DataBind();
excel.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output));

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: this not worked with me it is output excel file but it contains table related to https protocols like `(SERVER_PORT_SECURE, SERVER_PROTOCOL,SERVER_SOFTWARE)` and think i don't really what is it ...  it seems better way sinces we do not need to override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`... can you help me ??

Comment: what I have missed ? I put that code in method and call it from button `onclick` event

Comment: do i need a return anything?

Comment: @chungtinhlakho, this method renders an HTML table and writes it in the Response stream; if you're experiencing a different problem, ask a new question ;)

Answer (score 5):

Below link is used to export datatable to excel in C# Code.

http://royalarun.blogspot.in/2012/01/export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-windows.html

```
  using System;      
   using System.Data;  
   using System.IO;  
   using System.Windows.Forms;  

    namespace ExportExcel  
    {      
        public partial class ExportDatatabletoExcel : Form  
        {  
            public ExportDatatabletoExcel()  
            {  
                InitializeComponent();  
            }  

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                //Add Datacolumn
                DataColumn workCol = dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(String));

                dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("Blog", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(String));

                //Add in the datarow
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();

                newRow["firstname"] = "Arun";
                newRow["lastname"] = "Prakash";
                newRow["Blog"] = "http://royalarun.blogspot.com/";
                newRow["city"] = "Coimbatore";
                newRow["country"] = "India";

                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

                //open file
                StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"D:\\Book1.xls");

                try
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        wr.Write(dt.Columns[i].ToString().ToUpper() + "\t");
                    }

                    wr.WriteLine();

                    //write rows to excel file
                    for (int i = 0; i < (dt.Rows.Count); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows[i][j] != null)
                            {
                                wr.Write(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]) + "\t");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                wr.Write("\t");
                            }
                        }
                        //go to next line
                        wr.WriteLine();
                    }
                    //close file
                    wr.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually it is not an excel creation procedure. it generates the plain text in a tab-delimited form and saving the data in file having .xls extension. As Microsoft Excel software is aware of opening .such files, people think it is an excel document. Open the same file in any plain text editor such as "Notepad" or "EditPlus" and you will get to know. Microsoft Excel document follows  OLE principles.

I hope this helps whoever is trying to follow this thread.

Answer (score 5):

The most rank answer in this post work, however its is CSV file. It is not actual Excel file. Therefore, you will get a warning when you are opening a file.

The best solution I found on the web is using CloseXML
https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml
You need to  Open XML as well.

```
 dt = city.GetAllCity();//your datatable
 using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView.xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Credit: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Solution-ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel-The-file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in-a-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension.aspx

Comment: @jefissu it seems the close XML has known issues with older versions of the .Net Frame work
https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/450

Answer (score 2):

I use This in page.`

```
 public void DTToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    // dosya isimleri ileride aynı anda birden fazla kullanıcı aynı dosya üzerinde işlem yapmak ister düşüncesiyle guid yapıldı. 
    string FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("Downloads") + string.Format("\\{0}.xlsx", FileName));
    if (f.Exists)
        f.Delete(); // delete the file if it already exist.

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ".xls");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
    //response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());


    // create a string writer
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) //datatable'a aldığımız sorguyu bir datagrid'e atayıp html'e çevir.
        {
            // instantiate a datagrid
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            dg.DataSource = dt;
            dg.DataBind();
            dg.RenderControl(htw);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
            dg.Dispose();
            dt.Dispose();
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Volkan that was best way sinces we do not need to override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` .... Volkan I really appreciate it you set comments on each line to explain what's happening and that would be useful for others too.. **I Recommend that way dears Searcher**

Comment: Volkan please dear when I uncomment that line ... I get error I was trying to understand it is purpose ?  `//response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());`

Comment: I have add some comment for the line I understands please provide more ... Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
            var lines = new List<string>();

            string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                              Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                              ToArray();

            var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
            lines.Add(header);
            var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
            lines.AddRange(valueLines);
            File.WriteAllLines("excel.csv", lines);
```

Here dt refers to your DataTable pass as a paramter

Answer (score 0):

While not a .NET implementation, you may find that the plug-in `TableTools` may be highly effective depending on your audience. It relies upon flash which shouldn't be a problem for most cases of needing to actually work in-depth and then want to record tabular information.

The latest version appears to support copying to clipboard, into a CSV, ".XLS" (really just a tab-delimited file named .xls), to a PDF, or create a printer friendly page version with all rows displayed and the rest of your page's contents hidden.

I found the extension on the DataTables site here: http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

The download is available in the plug-ins (extras) page here: http://datatables.net/extras/

It supposedly is downloaded as a part of DataTables (hence the phrase "Extras included in the DataTables package") but I didn't find it in the download I have been using. Seems to work wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are actually producing the CSV which I don't always have good experience with, when opening in Excel.

One way of doing it would be also with [ACE OLEDB Provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB_provider) (see also [connection strings for Excel](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/)). Of course you'd have to have the provider installed and registered. You do have it, if you have Excel installed, but this is something you have to consider when deploying (e.g. on web server).

In below helper class code you'd have to call something like `ExportHelper.CreateXlsFromDataTable(dataset.Tables[0], @"C:\tmp\export.xls");`

```
public class ExportHelper
{
    private const string ExcelOleDbConnectionStringTemplate = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";";

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the Excel file from items in DataTable and writes them to specified output file.
    /// </summary>
    public static void CreateXlsFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, string fullFilePath)
    {
        string createTableWithHeaderScript = GenerateCreateTableCommand(dataTable);

        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format(ExcelOleDbConnectionStringTemplate, fullFilePath)))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableWithHeaderScript, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            foreach (DataRow dataExportRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                AddNewRow(conn, dataExportRow);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddNewRow(OleDbConnection conn, DataRow dataRow)
    {
        string insertCmd = GenerateInsertRowCommand(dataRow);

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, conn))
        {
            AddParametersWithValue(cmd, dataRow);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the insert row command.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GenerateInsertRowCommand(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var columns = dataRow.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
        var columnNamesCommaSeparated = string.Join(",", columns.Select(x => x.Caption));
        var questionmarkCommaSeparated = string.Join(",", columns.Select(x => "?"));

        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO [{0}] (", dataRow.Table.TableName);
        stringBuilder.Append(columnNamesCommaSeparated);
        stringBuilder.Append(") VALUES(");
        stringBuilder.Append(questionmarkCommaSeparated);
        stringBuilder.Append(")");
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the parameters with value.
    /// </summary>
    private static void AddParametersWithValue(OleDbCommand cmd, DataRow dataRow)
    {
        var paramNumber = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= dataRow.Table.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(dataRow.Table.Columns[i].DataType, typeof(int)) && !ReferenceEquals(dataRow.Table.Columns[i].DataType, typeof(decimal)))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + paramNumber, dataRow[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''"));
            }
            else
            {
                object value = GetParameterValue(dataRow[i]);
                OleDbParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + paramNumber, value);
                if (value is decimal)
                {
                    parameter.OleDbType = OleDbType.Currency;
                }
            }

            paramNumber = paramNumber + 1;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the formatted value for the OleDbParameter.
    /// </summary>
    private static object GetParameterValue(object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return value.ToString().Replace("'", "''");
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static string GenerateCreateTableCommand(DataTable tableDefination)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        bool firstcol = true;

        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE [{0}] (", tableDefination.TableName);

        foreach (DataColumn tableColumn in tableDefination.Columns)
        {
            if (!firstcol)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(", ");
            }
            firstcol = false;

            string columnDataType = "CHAR(255)";

            switch (tableColumn.DataType.Name)
            {
                case "String":
                    columnDataType = "CHAR(255)";
                    break;
                case "Int32":
                    columnDataType = "INTEGER";
                    break;
                case "Decimal":
                    // Use currency instead of decimal because of bug described at 
                    // http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d6248a5-ef00-4f46-be9d-853207656bcc/localization-trouble-with-oledbparameter-and-decimal?forum=csharpgeneral
                    columnDataType = "CURRENCY";
                    break;
            }

            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", tableColumn.ColumnName, columnDataType);
        }
        stringBuilder.Append(")");

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code for Excel Export

```
 try
        {
            DataTable dt = DS.Tables[0];
            string attachment = "attachment; filename=log.xls";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            string tab = "";
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
            int i;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                tab = "";
                for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                    tab = "\t";
                }
                Response.Write("\n");
            }
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        { }
```

Comment: Why have you reposted the accepted answer as your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try this to export the data to Excel file same as in DataTable and could customize also.

```
dtDataTable1 = ds.Tables[0];
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

        for (int i = 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Sheets xlSheets = null;
            Worksheet xlWorksheet = null;
            //Create Excel sheet
            xlSheets = ExcelApp.Sheets;
            xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlWorksheet.Name = "MY FIRST EXCEL FILE";
            for (int j = 1; j < dtDataTable1.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = dtDataTable1.Columns[j - 1].ColumnName;
                ExcelApp.Cells[1, j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke);
            }
            // for the data of the excel
            for (int k = 0; k < dtDataTable1.Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < dtDataTable1.Columns.Count; l++)
                {
                    ExcelApp.Cells[k + 2, l + 1] = dtDataTable1.Rows[k].ItemArray[l].ToString();
                }
            }
            ExcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
        }
        ((Worksheet)ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count]).Delete();
        ExcelApp.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you to export datatable to excel with formatted header text try like this.

```
public void ExportFullDetails()
    {
        Int16 id = Convert.ToInt16(Session["id"]);
        DataTable registeredpeople = new DataTable();
        registeredpeople = this.dataAccess.ExportDetails(eventid);

        string attachment = "attachment; filename=Details.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = "";


        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_id"].ColumnName = "Reg. ID";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Name"].ColumnName = "Name";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_country"].ColumnName = "Country";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_city"].ColumnName = "City";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_email"].ColumnName = "Email";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_business_phone"].ColumnName = "Business Phone";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_mobile"].ColumnName = "Mobile";
        registeredpeople.Columns["PositionRole"].ColumnName = "Position";
        registeredpeople.Columns["Reg_work_type"].ColumnName = "Work Type";

        foreach (DataColumn dc in registeredpeople.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }

        Response.Write("\n");
        int i;
        foreach (DataRow dr in registeredpeople.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < registeredpeople.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done the DataTable to Excel conversion with the following code. Hope it's very easy no need to change more just copy & pest the code replace your variable with your variable, and it will work properly.

First create a folder in your solution **Document**, and create an Excel file **MyTemplate.xlsx**. you can change those name according to your requirement. But remember for that you have to change the name in code also.

Please find the following code...

```
    protected void GetExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

        ManageTicketBS objManageTicket = new ManageTicketBS();
        DataTable DT = objManageTicket.GetAlldataByDate();   //this function will bring the data in DataTable format, you can use your function instate of that.  

        string DownloadFileName;
        string FolderPath;
        string FileName = "MyTemplate.xlsx";
        DownloadFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName) + new Random().Next(10000, 99999) + Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        FolderPath = ".\\" + DownloadFileName;

        GetParents(Server.MapPath("~/Document/" + FileName), Server.MapPath("~/Document/" + DownloadFileName), DT);

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Document/" + FolderPath);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.ContentType = MimeType(Path.GetExtension(FolderPath));
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + DownloadFileName);
                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                response.BinaryWrite(data);
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                response.End();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteOrganisationtoSupplierTemplate(path);
            }
        }
    }
    public string GetParents(string FilePath, string TempFilePath, DataTable DTTBL)
    {
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(FilePath), Path.Combine(TempFilePath), true);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(TempFilePath);
        try
        {
            DatatableToExcel(DTTBL, TempFilePath, 0);

            return TempFilePath;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            return "";
        }

    }


    public static string MimeType(string Extension)
    {
        string mime = "application/octetstream";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Extension))
            return mime;
        string ext = Extension.ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        if (rk != null && rk.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            mime = rk.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
        return mime;
    }


    static bool DeleteOrganisationtoSupplierTemplate(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {                
            File.Delete(filePath);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {               
            return false;
        }
    }


    public void DatatableToExcel(DataTable dtable, string pFilePath, int excelSheetIndex=1)
    {

        try
        {
            if (dtable != null && dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                IWorkbook workbook = null;
                ISheet worksheet = null;

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {

                    workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(stream);
                    worksheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(excelSheetIndex);

                    int iRow = 1;



                    foreach (DataRow row in dtable.Rows)
                    {
                        IRow file = worksheet.CreateRow(iRow);
                        int iCol = 0;
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dtable.Columns)
                        {
                            ICell cell = null;
                            object cellValue = row[iCol];

                            switch (column.DataType.ToString())
                            {
                                case "System.Boolean":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.Boolean);

                                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(cellValue)) { cell.SetCellFormula("TRUE()"); }
                                        else { cell.SetCellFormula("FALSE()"); }

                                        //cell.CellStyle = _boolCellStyle;
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "System.String":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.String);
                                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToString(cellValue));
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "System.Int32":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.Numeric);
                                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToInt32(cellValue));
                                        //cell.CellStyle = _intCellStyle;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "System.Int64":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.Numeric);
                                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToInt64(cellValue));
                                        //cell.CellStyle = _intCellStyle;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "System.Decimal":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.Numeric);
                                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(cellValue));
                                        //cell.CellStyle = _doubleCellStyle;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "System.Double":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.Numeric);
                                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(cellValue));
                                        //cell.CellStyle = _doubleCellStyle;
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "System.DateTime":
                                    if (cellValue != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        cell = file.CreateCell(iCol, CellType.String);
                                        DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue);
                                        cell.SetCellValue(dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

                                        DateTime cDate = Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue);
                                        if (cDate != null && cDate.Hour > 0)
                                        {
                                            //cell.CellStyle = _dateTimeCellStyle; 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            // cell.CellStyle = _dateCellStyle; 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            iCol++;
                        }
                        iRow++;
                    }
                    using (var WritetoExcelfile = new FileStream(pFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        workbook.Write(WritetoExcelfile);
                        WritetoExcelfile.Close();
                        //workbook.Write(stream);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This code you just need to copy & pest in your script and add the **Namespace** as following, Also change the excel file name as previously discussed.

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, this will export your data table data's faster to excel.

Note: Range "FW", that I have hard coded is because I had 179 columns.

```
public void UpdateExcelApplication(SqlDataTable dataTable)
    {
        var objects = new string[dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count];

        var rowIndex = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var colIndex = 0;

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                objects[rowIndex, colIndex++] = Convert.ToString(row[column]);
            }

            rowIndex++;
        }

        var range = this.workSheet.Range[$"A3:FW{dataTable.Rows.Count + 2}"];
        range.Value = objects;

        this.workSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        this.workSheet.Rows.AutoFit();
    }
```

Comment: what is a type of `worksheet'. Where it is declared, initialized..