# Export DataTable to Excel File in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

I have read this article that exports datatable to excel file.
It worked great.

[Export DataTable to Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746701/export-datatable-to-excel-file)

and the code is below:

```
dt = city.GetAllCity();//your datatable 
string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls"; 
Response.ClearContent(); 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment); 
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
string tab = ""; 
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) 
{ 
    Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName); 
    tab = "\t"; 
} 
Response.Write("\n"); 
int i; 
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
{ 
    tab = ""; 
    for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) 
    { 
        Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString()); 
        tab = "\t"; 
    } 
    Response.Write("\n"); 
} 
Response.End();
```

But when I use this codes, the korean characters are all broken.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: It may be down to Excel not recognising the unicode need to display the characters. You probably need a header to indicate that.

Comment: which header shall I indicate?

Comment: ContentType charset http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses make sure you include UTF8 as shown in the article

Comment: Of course I put utf-8 in head. Anything else??

Answer (score 2):

I use `windows-1254` character set for Turkish. I guess `KS_X_1001` will work for you.
For more sets : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
Response.Charset = "windows-1254";
```