# Visual Basic - Writing a Datatable to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, datatable, export

I am working on a console application that will grab all of the .sql files in a specific folder, use those to query a database, and then export the results of each to an excel file. I've gotten everything down up to the datatable. I am asking for any advice or guidance on getting that datatable to excel. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

---

```
Module SqlExport

Sub Main()

    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim SQLDirectory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("\\Datastore\scripts\SQL")
    Dim SQLQueries As IO.FileInfo() = SQLDirectory.GetFiles("*.sql")
    Dim CurrentQuery As IO.FileInfo

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    For Each CurrentQuery In SQLQueries
        SQLString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(CurrentQuery.FullName)

        Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=advantage ole db provider;data source=\\database\dba;advantage server type=ads_remote_server;trimtrailingspaces=true;")

            Dim command As New OleDbCommand(SQLString, connection)
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

            da.Fill(dt)

        End Using

    Next

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: The first suggested link on the right looks perfect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746701/export-datatable-to-excel-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for this. I ended up using the following to get the results I was looking for.

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

da.Fill(ds)

Dim Excel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With Excel
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        .Workbooks.Add()
        .Worksheets(1).Select()
        .Range("A1").select()

        Dim i As Integer = 1

        For col = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            If Asc(ds.Tables(0).Columns(col).ColumnName) = 36 Then
                .Columns(i).NumberFormat = "General"
                .Cells(1, i).value = ds.Tables(0).Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(1)
            Else
                .Columns(i).NumberFormat = "@"
                .Cells(1, i).value = ds.Tables(0).Columns(col).ColumnName
            End If
            i += 1
        Next

        Dim j As Integer = 1
        For col = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            i = 2
            For row = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                .Cells(i, j).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(row).ItemArray(col).ToString
                i += 1
            Next
            j += 1
        Next

        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentQuery.Name)

        .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:="\\reports\" & value & "\" & fileName & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ".xlsx", _
        WriteResPassword:="123456", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False)

        .Workbooks.Close()
        .Quit()
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In Manual way ..

First you have to create your XLS file and make colums header like fields in your database

Assumed that is "TRANSFER.XLS" ..

```
Dim sFN = "Transfer.XLS"
Dim cnXLS As OleDbConnection
Dim cmdXLS As OleDbCommand
Dim dr as DataRow

cnXLS = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "data source=" & sFN & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
cnXLS.Open()

For x as Integer = 0 to dt.Table(0).Rows.Count -1 '---> this is your dt
  dr = dt.Table(0).Rows(x)
  cmdXLS = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ( name, .... ) VALUES ( dr.item("name", ....)", cnXLS)
  cmdXLS.ExecuteNonQuery

Next
cnXLS.close()
```