# Datatable to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable

Iam Exporting data from datatable to excel ,i referred the below link and implemented the same

[Export DataTable to Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746701/export-datatable-to-excel-file][1])

The problem iam facing is when opening Excel it is showing the file you are trying to open is in different format.What can i do to resolve this error

The Code i used  is

```
 dt = city.GetAllCity();//your datatable
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
    Response.End();
```

Comment: You need to check which version of excel is installed on your system. and you need to use that extension in your code.

Comment: You are writing a tab-delimited file but saying it's a "native" xls file: Excel used to put up with that but for the last few versions that gets you the warning about the file format.  See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948615