# How to Export Datatable to Excel file using ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, excel

I have tried this [Export DataTable to Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746701/export-datatable-to-excel-file) I am able to download excel file when I am calling through SOAP API but when I am calling it from ajax I am not getting any error and I am not able to download the Excel File.

Ajax/JavaScript Code:

```
function getWorkOrders(wono) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: 'AdminWeb.asmx/GetWorkOrdersDetails',
            data: 'id=0&wono=' + wono,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
    },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
    });
    }
```

Method:

```
DataTable dtResult = DataAccess.GetDataTableFromStoredProcedure("sp_Get_WO", Parameters);

    //dt = city.GetAllCity();//your datatable
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtResult.Columns)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dtResult.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\n");
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] or some code at least. It's probably going to be a Mime Type thing in IIS also state what web browsers you've tried and a Wireshark/Netmon trace when you're downloading via Ajax vs another via SOAP

Comment: @JeremyThompson Please check the above code.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I want to export the excel file with specific search data i dont to download the file which is already imported.

Comment: Your ajax call won't give you any errors, since you don't have an error callback defined

Comment: @Marco I have tried with error callback as well